# Atom Red Highlight after single quote (')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How to disable specific instances of the red highlighting.

I've tried entering an escape before the single quote, but it didn't work. I'm certain the single quote is causing the red highlighting because when I remove it, it goes away.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const banner = () => {

  return <p>Tristan\'s first React site!</p>
};

export default banner;
```

Comment: try this  { ` Tristan's ... ` }

Comment: I think you are escaping it wrong, you should use  \ (back slash) for escaping, not / (forward slash)

Comment: Honestly, I thought that too so I tried both. Will edit it to not cause confusion in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The red highlight" is coming from `eslint`. I don't know which configuration you are using but this warning is for [no-unescaped-entities](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unescaped-entities.md)

So you can fix it by using like:

```
<p>Tristan&apos;s first React site!</p>
```

or by using other options that you can find that link.

You can use something like:

```
{`Tristan's first React site!`}
```

or

```
<p>{'Tristan\'s first React site!'}</p>
```

or

```
<p>{"Tristan\'s first React site!"}</p>
```

as suggested in the comments and the other answers, but this probably causes another warning: [jsx-curly-brace-presence](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-curly-brace-presence.md)

Comment: This worked. Before the {} were added the app would render a string with "s in order to not highlight everything after an ' in a string. 

After wrapping the string in {}'s the "s aren't rendered to the app (page) and the 's are still rendered.

Comment: As I tried to explain those "red highlight"s are coming from your linter. If you hover on this line you can get some information and a link. Go that link and read the explanation. Linters are good for learning best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```js
import React from 'react';

const banner = () => {

  return <p>{'Tristan\'s first React site!'}</p>
};

export default banner;
```